# Accessing the Application Object of an Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get to the Application object of an Access DB without opening the DB. I was able to do this a couple days ago, but have lost the code.
I'm finding lots of websites that use OpenDatabase or GetObject, but both of those try to open the DB.

The reason I don't want to open it is because it's corrupted and I'm trying to issue a "Save as text" on each object. Opening it just crashes it.

And, yes, I have tried to just import the objects.

**Still looking for an answer to the primary question. That is, how to access the remote application object. Thanks**

Thanks

P.S. If you have any other suggestions for retrieving the objects in the corrupted DB, it would be welcome.

Comment: "I was able to do this a couple days ago, but have lost the code" - say what?

Comment: Have you tried repairing it?

Comment: In other words, I no longer have the code that I'm looking for, and can't find it doing a search. And, yes, I have tried repairing it.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving Objects from a Corrupt Database.

First Try to repair it.
Second Create a new database and import one object at a time.  Normally a single form is corrupt and sometimes Access just doesn't like you trying to import them all at once.

You can also write code to remotely compact and repair databases, but it's been a long time since I've done that and can't quite remember how ATM.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [Jetcomp](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273956)?  That sometimes fixes things the regular compact doesn't.

Comment: That only handles up to Microsoft Office 2000. It may even work on up to 2005. But I'm using 2010, an .accdb file.